# Distributed evaluation of Inception in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, cluster-computing, distributed

I know [Distributed Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) allows one to train on a cluster in a distributed setting. Is there a chance to do the `evaluation` on a cluster as well? Has anyone accomplished that? Sharing your code here would be nice for all readers as well.